# How to create checkbox inside li dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve following html

```
 <li class="default_filter"><input type="checkbox" name="someName"/></li>
```

I tried:

```
 var dome= "$('.ulContainer')";

  var li= $('<li/>').text(data[i]).appendTo(dom);

  var cbx=$('<input type='checkbox'/>').name("someName").appendTo(li);
```

Comment: And did that produce an error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.ulContainer').append('<li class="default_filter">' + data[i] + '<input type="checkbox" name="someName"/></li>');
```

Comment: dynamically i have to create multiple elements based on array

Comment: You can put text for li by appending `data[i]` to the string, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If Javascript can do you can use below:

```
//loop starts here 
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = 'default_filter';

var inputCB =  document.createElement('input');
inputCB.type = 'checkbox';
inputCB.setAttribute('name','someName');

li.appendChild(inputCB);

$('.ulContainer').append(li);
//loop ends here.
```

You can use it in a loop to Make multiple li's